# Read from a .msg file

Tags: python, msg

I am tryign to read the content of a `.msg` file.

I looked into other similar questions and I found the solution that does not break for me is using `olefile` (https://pypi.org/project/olefile/).

My code is currently:

```
import olefile

def read_msg(file_name):
  if file_name.lower().endswith(('.msg')):
    with olefile.OleFileIO(file_name) as ole:
      meta = ole.get_metadata()
      meta.dump()

    return "something"


read_msg('my_msg_file.msg')
```

**HOWEVER** I do not understand how I can extract the text from it.

With `meta.dump()`I can extract the metadata but not the "body" of the .msg.

Answer (score 0):

Try using as,

```
import sys,olefile

x=olefile.OleFileIO('dkd.msg')
y = x.openstream('WordDocument')
print y.read()
```

Comment: It gives me an error on the `y = x.openstream('WordDocument')`. The error is: `raise IOError("file not found")`. The file does open, if I `print(x)`it shows `<olefile.olefile.OleFileIO object at 0x10242b470>`

Comment: https://olefile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Howto.html#overwriting-a-stream .  -  try using like this